# Generic extending of generic class .net

Tags: c#, generics, extending

I have a base class which is a core model for many applications. This class uses generics.

```
public class CoreBaseModel<TModel> where TModel : CoreBaseModel<TModel>, new() {
    public string connectionString = "...";
    //lots of member
}
```

For every application, I want to extend this base class and override some members(for example the connection string).

```
public class CurrentAppBaseModel<TModel> where TModel : CoreBaseModel<TModel>, new() {
    public string connectionString = "Data Source=...";
}
```

Inside the applications, I extend this class for every model(lets say Address, Employee, etc...). This classes should be generics as well, because I use Lists of the current classes, incase I want to return the same model in a collection.

```
public class AddressModel : CurrentAppBaseModel<AddressModel> {
    //lots of member
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to write the CurrentAppBaseModel since it still needs to use generics, but also needs to extend the base.

The first and

Comment: I don't exactly understand your problem. Your code should work as is. (Hint: don't use public fields)

Comment: @knittl: I can't build it, because its says that the
The type 'AddressModel' cannot be used as type paramter 'TModel' in the generic type or method CurrentAppBaseModel<TModel>. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'AddressModel' to 'CoreBaseModel<AddressModel>'.
and also:
AddressModel.someMethod: no suitable method found to override.

Comment: Try `AddressModel : CurrentAppBaseModel<CoreBaseModel<AddressModel>>`, maybe that works? Or maybe you want `CurrentAppBaseModel<TModel> : CoreBaseModel<TModel>`?